# Passing parameters to dynamically generated react routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm using `react-router-dom` and generate my routes dynamically from an array like so

**Routes Data**

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    exact: true,
    component: () => <MyComponent />
  }
}
```

**Route Generation**

```
{routes.map((route, index) => {
  return <Route
    key={index}
    path={route.path}
    exact={route.exact}
    component={route.component}
  />
})}
```

Render Prop
I found out about the render() prop I could define but even so how do I do this since the component is inside a variable

```
const props = this.props;
{routes.map((route, index) => {
  return <Route
    key={index}
    path={route.path}
    exact={route.exact}
    render={(props) => <??? {...props} />
  />
})}
```

How can I pass this.props during the route generation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change your array to just include the component instead of a new function component that renders the component and you will get the props sent to it:

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    exact: true,
    component: MyComponent
  }
}
```

You can use any capitalized variable as a component, so you could also do this if you prefer:

```
{routes.map((route, index) => {
  const Component = route.component;

  return <Route
    key={index}
    path={route.path}
    exact={route.exact}
    render={(props) => <Component {...props} />
  />
})}
```

Comment: ah thank you Tholle this is great! How would you handle the redirect cases? For instance my array in my actual implementation has some routes objects where the component is a redirect such as   ```{
     path: '/',
     exact: true,
     component: <Redirect to='/other/route' />
   },
```
I'm thinking maybe add an extra field redirect: '/other/route' to my routes object and then in my loop do a condition if that was defined?

Comment: @Newton You're welcome! For that the second approach might be best. `{ component: MyComponent }` for regular components, and `{ component: () => <Redirect to='/other/route' /> }` for your redirects should work. Adding a separate field `redirect: '/other/route'` should work great as well.

Comment: all set, everything works, thanks again Tholle, really appreciate it!